# How to pick the latest file to archive in a folder in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a multiple files in a folder date-wise like: accnt20140127,accnt20140128,accnt20140129,accnt20140130,accnt20140131 etc

I want to pick the latest file ie. accnt20140131 and copy to a seperate folder.

can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (
  ' dir /o-n /b /a-d "c:\folder\accnt*"' 
) do ( set "fileName=%%f"  & goto done )
:done
echo "%fileName%"
```

Ordering by filename, descending, the first file is the latest. Take its name and exit the `for`